# What mechanism does David Weber use to ensure internal consistency of works in the shared Honorverse?

Tags: writing-process, david-weber, honorverse

In certain franchises/shared universes, there are well known mechanisms for ensuring internal consistency (E.g. Star Wars has LucasFilm's Holocron/LSG).

David Weber's [Honorverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorverse) is a shared universe of books/stories, where other writers participate as well as Weber himself.

Is there a mechanism that Weber uses for ensuring the universe's internal consistency? (Database? forum? specific set of people? his own memory?)

Comment: meta question discussing whether this question type is in-scope: http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/19/are-questions-about-the-process-of-creating-specific-literary-works-on-topic?noredirect=1#comment16_19

Comment: From the wikipedia article of the honorverse: (unsourced, not sufficient for an answer): "The series' canon is maintained solely by its creator, who acts as editor in the few works in the universe by other collaborating authors."

Comment: "          Once I'd chosen my historical template, I sat down and constructed the basic universe: political units, available technologies, naval strategic and tactical doctrines, historical evolution, etc... And, I will confess, I deliberately constructed my navel technological toolbox in a way which would create something with clear parallels between three-dimensional space-going warfare and the two-dimensional broadside warfare of the eighteenth century." http://www.davidweber.net/faqs/index/page:3/series:3

Comment: @VicAche - doesn't answer exaustively (since doesn't explain what methodology he uses for editing), but definitely enough info for an answer.